# Check if value of one property is present in value of another property in JSON Schema validation?

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

Can I validate this json using json schema validation using the following conditions :

1. name and email both are string
2. The email should contain the value of the name property, like in the given example if email was "xyz@gmail.com" then the json would be invalid but since contains "abc" it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

In jsonschema it's not possible to reference arbitrary, dynamic values from the data to be validated and use it as part of the schema validation. See [this discussion](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51) for more context around the reasoning. However:

If you can enumerate all values of a property, you can use `oneOf` & `const` to apply specific constraints for each value. Judging from your example it looks that this is not useful to you.

If you can't enumerate all the values you can't use standard jsonschema. Some validator libraries implement *non-standard* features that can help you. For example, [Avj implements a `$data` keyword](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html#data-reference) that can solve your issue. But keep in mind that this solution is tied to Avj - other validators will ignore this keyword.